# Transition effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am displaying a backdrop on every change happening in my app. But I want that to happen with a little transition, like a kind of fade-in - fade-out

this is what I have

```
  $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 150, 'linear');
  $('.backdrop').css('display', 'block');
```

now, I am using angular but as this is a Directive I did that way:

```
  <light-box>
    <div class="backdrop" ng-show="displayBackdrop">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </light-box>
```

so, when `$rootScope.displayBackdrop = true` the `light-box` comes up to the screen

```
.directive('lightBox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
      $('.backdrop').css('display', 'block');
    }
  };
});
```

here de css

```
.backdrop
    {
      position:fixed;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      background:#000;
      opacity: .0;
      filter:alpha(opacity=0);
      z-index:300;
      display:none;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at ng-animate, better than using jQuery imo: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeToggle`, `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` depending on your need, with optional parameters specified within the square braces:

```
$('.backdrop').fadeToggle([duration], [easing], [complete/callback]);
```

Comment: I changed it to fadeToggle and it is not doing anything :(

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Can you show some more code? I can't see how you're calling the animations etc.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Is your link function running at all?

Comment: yes, it is working, the issue is that I am not getting the animation I want

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Are you sure you want the ng-show on the backdrop div and not the lightbox element?

Comment: it is not important here. all I need is the animation

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Can you provide a plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few demos of JQuery transitions:
3 parameters are": duration, easing and callback functions.

```js
var test = $('#test'),
  $in = $('#in'),
  out = $('#out'),
  toggle = $('#toggle'),
  to = $('#to');


$in.click(function() {
  test.fadeIn(1000, function() {});
});


out.click(function() {
  test.fadeOut(1000, function() {});
});


toggle.click(function() {
  test.fadeToggle(1000, function() {});
});

to.click(function() {
  test.fadeTo(1000, 0.5, function() {});
});
```

```css
#test {
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>
  <button id="in">fadeIn()</button>
  <button id="out">fadeOut()</button>
  <button id="toggle">fadeToggle()</button>
  <button id="to">fadeTo()</button>
</p>
<div id="test"></div>
```